# iOS - View rotate and resize

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Here is myView

[image: Here is myView]

When

```
self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0/180);

[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake:(self.myView.frame.orgin.x,self.myView.frame.orgin.y,300,self.myView.frame.size.height)];
```

it will be

[image]

now when i rotate the view

[image]

And do this again

```
self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0/180);

[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake:(self.myView.frame.orgin.x,self.myView.frame.orgin.y,300,self.myView.frame.size.height)];
```

[image]

What happened here?

seen like the width is stretched.

Its anyway to fix it or have other way to rotate and resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `bounds` and `center` properties to resize and place your view, frame should not be used if the transform property is not the identity transform

(see warning at the [UIView documentation for frame](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame))

`frame.size` is not equal to `bounds.size` when your view is rotated, if you want your view to have a width of 300, you should set the bounds